# taggit import error when using django with zinnia

Tags: python, django, tagging, django-taggit, zinnia

I have a django app in which i am trying to use `django-taggit` and zinnia blog, below are my settings and code

**directory structure**

```
test_app
   apps
     app_one
         __init__.py
         views.py
         forms.py   
         urls.py
         models
             taggit_custom.py    
     app_two
   settings
     local_settings.py
   manage.py
```

**local_settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'taggit',
    'zinnia',
)
```

**taggit_custom.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.conf import settings
from taggit.models import TaggedItem

class CustomModel_one(models.Model):
    ......
    ......
```

So from the above i am trying to use `django-zinnia-blog` for my site as blog, but i want to use `django-taggit` instead of `tagging`, and just given a try to use `taggit`,
so installed taggit by `pip install django-taggit`

But when i tried to use the taggit application as above like `from taggit.models import TaggedItem` its displaying the below error

**Note:** Infact no imports from taggit module like

```
from taggit.models import TaggedItem
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.forms........ etc.,
```

are working even though the application is installed(Also checked by `pip freeze` and taggit is there :))

**result**

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x9902e8c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True
  ......
  ......
 File "/home/user/name/virtualenvironment/apps/test_app/models/taggit_custom.py", line 4, in <module>
    from taggit.models import TaggedItem
ImportError: No module named models
```

So can anyone please let me know why taggit importing is not working even though taggit has been installed ?

**Edited**

Also when i tried something like below

(Inside virtual env)

```
import taggit
print dir(taggit.models)
```

result

```
['Aggregate', 'AutoField', 'Avg', 'BLANK_CHOICE_DASH', 'BLANK_CHOICE_NONE', 'BigIntegerField', 'BooleanField', 'CASCADE', 'CharField', 'CommaSeparatedIntegerField', 'Count', 'DO_NOTHING', 'DateField', 'DateTimeField', 'DecimalField', 'DictWrapper', 'EmailField', 'F', 'Field', 'FieldDoesNotExist', 'FileField', 'FilePathField', 'FloatField', 'ForeignKey', 'GenericIPAddressField', 'IPAddressField', 'ImageField', 'ImproperlyConfigured', 'IntegerField', 'Manager', 'ManyToManyField', 'ManyToManyRel', 'ManyToOneRel', 'Max', 'Min', 'Model', 'NOT_PROVIDED', 'NullBooleanField', 'ObjectDoesNotExist', 'OneToOneField', 'OneToOneRel', 'PROTECT', 'PositiveIntegerField', 'PositiveSmallIntegerField', 'ProtectedError', 'Q', 'QueryWrapper', 'SET', 'SET_DEFAULT', 'SET_NULL', 'SlugField', 'SmallIntegerField', 'StdDev', 'SubfieldBase', 'Sum', 'TextField', 'TimeField', 'URLField', 'Variance', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'aggregates', 'base', 'capfirst', 'clean_ipv6_address', 'connection', 'constants', 'copy', 'curry', 'datetime', 'decimal', 'deletion', 'exceptions', 'expressions', 'fields', 'force_text', 'forms', 'get_app', 'get_apps', 'get_model', 'get_models', 'is_iterator', 'loading', 'manager', 'math', 'options', 'parse_date', 'parse_datetime', 'parse_time', 'permalink', 'proxy', 'query', 'query_utils', 'register_models', 'related', 'settings', 'signals', 'six', 'smart_text', 'sql', 'tee', 'timezone', 'total_ordering', 'unicode_literals', 'validators', 'warnings', 'wraps']
```

so from the above whether taggit is working/installed ?
and but why its showing an error when i tried `from taggit.models import TaggedItem` ?

Comment: Can you execute that? `import sys; print sys.path` And see if you can see taggit in the list?

Comment: yes i can able to see an egg file lik `'/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_taggit-0.10-py2.7.egg'`, also BTW i am using `virtualenv` and installed all required apps in it

Comment: You didn't have the virtualenvironment activated when you install django-taggit; so install it again in the virtual environment.

Comment: yes ofcourse i installed in virtual env too, i had checked that by typing pip freeze and the result is as `'/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_taggit-0.10-py‌​2.7.egg'`

Comment: i was also getting the same error. Not sure about the cause, but i  deactivated my virtual env and installed it in the central installation(where python is installed). then it was working fine. But not sure why django skips the virtualenv.. might be due to some environment variable issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a 7 year old thread. But I'm sharing my experience for the future purpose, someone might be benefited from it.
I've just faced similar problem. I installed *django-taggit* (current version is 1.3.0) in my venv. I added it to *INSTALLED_APPS*. Later on I tried to import in my *models.py*. But it was showing import error. I restarted my *VSCode*. After a couple of minutes, like 1-2 minutes, it was fixed automatically. IDK, it was weird. Maybe it needs some time to get working.

So, if you installed it correctly (in the right env) then it should work. Just give it some time, maybe restart your IDE and try again.